# Uniform convergence of $n\chi_{[\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'd like some help with this question:
Show that the sequence $f_n$ defined by $f_n=n\chi_{[\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]}$ have the following property: given $\delta > 0$, it converges uniformly in $[ 0,\delta ]^C$ 
Thanks.

Comment: As soon as $n\gt2/\delta$, $f_n$ is identically zero in the complement of $[0,\delta]$. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what happens when you have $n > \frac{2}{\delta}$. In particular what is $f_n$ on $[0,\delta]^c$ when $n > \frac{2}{\delta}$.